# Using ruby and selenium webdriver how I can get class from "container"?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have the following form:

```
<div id="PaymentInfoDivContainer" class="checkout-section-container complete">
    <div class="checkout-section">
        <h3 class="sheen">
            <span class="step">2</span>
            Payment Information
        </h3>
    <a class="sc-button-white edit-button" onclick="SC.Checkout.Edit(this);"
 href="javascript:;">Edit</a>
    <div class="checkout-section-content">
</div>
```

Using Ruby and selenium webdriver, how I can get (and click) on "edit-button" class ?
As I understand I have to get and store in variable id="PaymentInfoDivContainer" and then use it to find the right class. Any thoughts/ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,You can go as below : [*CSS3 [attribute$=value] Selector*](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp)

```
driver.find_element(:css,'a[class$="edit-button"]').click
```

or

```
driver.find_element(:css,'div#PaymentInfoDivContainer>div>a').click
```

Comment: @y72 glad to help you out.